# Importing CSV file error

Tags: python-3.x, csv

When importing a CSV file in Python, how should I write the entire path for it? For ex:`"C:\Users\user\Downloads\insurance.csv"` or `("C:\Users\user\Downloads\insurance.csv")`? Currently, it gives me an error:

> the file doesn't exist

Comment: You need to change \ to / or \\ because python is reading those as break characters.

Comment: Improved text and legibility

Comment: Changed it to = filename = "C:\\Users\user\\Downloads\\insurance.csv"
              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 9-10: truncated \uXXXX escape

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no, it's like this.

```
data_folder = "source_data\\text_files\\"

file_to_open = data_folder + "raw_data.txt"

f = open(file_to_open)

print(f.read())
```

Or...this...

```
from pathlib import Path

data_folder = Path("source_data/text_files/")

file_to_open = data_folder / "raw_data.txt"

f = open(file_to_open)

print(f.read())
```

Comment: from pathlib import Path
data_folder = Path("source_data/text_files/")
file_to_open = data_folder / "raw_data.txt"
f = open(file_to_open)
print(f.read())        -------------------------- The Error message : FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-8ea239bb6109> in <module>()
      5 file_to_open = data_folder / "insurance.csv"
      6 
----> 7 f = open(file_to_open)
      8 
      9 print(f.read())

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source_data\\text_files\\insurance.csv'

Comment: It works fine for me.  What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: It's showing as No such file or directory: 'source_data\\text_files\\insurance.csv'

Comment: Maybe you misspelled something, or you have a space in the file path, or something like that.  Again, it works fine for me.  This is the standard way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Ok . I dont know what exactly I'm missing . See below : from pathlib import Path
data_folder = Path("C:/Users/user/Documents")
file_to_open = data_folder/"Abhi.docx"
f = open(file_to_open)
print(f.read())

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-164791f7f065> in <module>()
      7 f = open(file_to_open)
      8 
----> 9 print(f.read())

~\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

Comment: 22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 611: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Hey man . I'm able to execute it now . Thanks much . Good day !